# In python, run in parallel an executable .exe without waiting the .exe to be finished

Tags: python, parallel-processing, subprocess, execution

This is just an example, but more situations might arise. Suppose you have an executable from a "myscript.py" file, with a kind of infinite while-true, but it is actually a condition extracted from file,

```
# myscript.py file to be executed..

bool_condition = True
while bool_condition :
    bool_condition = pickle.load(open('file_condition.p','rb'))

    # -- script lines under while-condition -- #

# endwhile bool_condition
```

In principle it is infinite unless another script changes the content of file_condition.p. Consider now a GUI, that activation of the executable comes from pushing a button, and the stop of the executable comes from button-action as well, so that if you press the stop-button the content of condition.p changes, and therefore also the "bool_condition " variable from True to False, and therefore the execution stops.

The key is that when the start-button is pushed, there is a line that run the execution of "myscript" without waiting the end of execution of that line (because otherwise the start-botton freezes and you cannot press the stop-button). I know how to do that no-wait parallel execution from a python file "myscript.py" file,

```
pid = subprocess.Popen([os.sys.executable, "myscript.py"], 
      stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

however it does not work from a *.exe file, "myscript.exe",

```
# 1st try..

pid = subprocess.Popen([os.sys.executable, "myscript.exe"], 
      stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

# 2nd try..

pid = subprocess.Popen(os.system(myscript.exe), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
      stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

For me it is impossible to think that Python is uncapable of doing no-wait parallel execution of a *.exe file (i.e. without waiting end of execution like os.sys(myscript.exe) ). Is actually Python capable of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
pid = subprocess.Popen(["myscript.exe"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Passing absolute path to "myscript.exe" will also make whole invocation safer.

By passing `os.sys.executable` as first argument to Popen you effectively invoke python. This is fine, if you want to launch python script, but exe file aint a python scrypt, and this is why it didn't work.

Comment: I confirm it works. Thank you, your solution is simple and elegant